# Python string check against a particular pattern

Tags: python, regex

My requirement is that I want to print true if the string matches with the word "develop" or "develop[0-9]" . This is the python code I wrote

```py
import re
    
# Target String one
str  = ["develop","develop1","develop123","developtest","develop9_test"]
    
# pattern to find three consecutive digits
# compile string pattern to re.Pattern object
for i in range(0, len(str)):
    if re.match(r"develop\d", str[i]):
        print("true")
```

I want to print true only for the strings "develop", "develop1", and "develop123". Any help is appreciated? Above code also got syntax issue which I am not sure how to resolve it?

Comment: The error message clearly tells you the problem: `IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'for' statement on line 8`

Comment: First you say _I want to print true if the string matches with the word "develop" or "develop[0-9]"_, then you say _I want to print true only for the strings "develop","develop1","develop123"_.  Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of bad indentation. You forgot an indentation block on the before-to-last line. **In Python, indentation is not optional!**

Also, to match any number of digits after `develop` (including 0), you should add an `*` after `\d` to signal **zero or more** occurrences.

Finally, you should use [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) instead of [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) to match a string entirely, rather than just the beginning.

```py
import re

# Target String one
str = ["develop","develop1","develop123","developtest","develop9_test"]

# pattern to find three consecutive digits
# compile string pattern to re.Pattern object
for i in range(0, len(str)):
  if re.fullmatch(r"develop\d*", str[i]):
    print("true")
```

Answer (score 1):

To check a string in a particular Patten :

```
import re

# Target String one
str_list = ["develop","develop1","develop123","developtest","develop9_test"]

# pattern to find three consecutive digits
pattern = r"develop\d{3}"

# compile string pattern to re.Pattern object
regex = re.compile(pattern)

for s in str_list:
    if regex.search(s):
        print(f"'{s}' matches the pattern '{pattern}'")
    else:
        print(f"'{s}' does not match the pattern '{pattern}'")
```